# A value in a field in a database table needs to be validated against a list of valid values in a Flat File

Tags: sql, oracle

First, I am not a SQL script developer. I am just starting to learn SQL.

I have a flat file called Valid-Values.txt, that contains the following valid values:
- North End
- South End
- West End
- East End
- Middle

I have a database table called LOCATION. In the LOCATION table, I have two fields:
RECORD_NUM and PLACEMENT

If the value in the PLACEMENT field, is not one of the values in the Valid-Values.txt flat file, then output an error message along with the RECORD_NUM and the invalid value that is in the PLACEMENT field.

How would you write this SQL script?
Can you write an SQL script to check values in a field in a table against values in a flat file
or should I build a table with the valid values in the flat file?

Can you write an SQL script to check values in a flat file?

I need help trying to write the SQL for this logic, but I don't know where to start.

I would appreciate help.
Thanks

I haven't tried writing the script because I don't know how to write the script. I am looking for an example of how to do this.

Comment: *Must* the values be read from the file? Do they change often?

Comment: Perhaps [external tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-038ED956-A6EE-4C6D-B7C9-0D406B8088B6) is appropriate here?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Bohemian, the values in the VALID_VALUES flat file may change to include values as SOUTHWEST, NORTHEAST, .etc. Thanks

Comment: Abra, I will look into building an external table with the valid values. Thanks

Comment: jarlh, thanks for the education.

Answer (score 0):

**We can follow below steps to solve this problem:**

- consider you are using sql database and you have permission to use the bulk load statement
- Consider below table schema and insert statement

```
create table LOCATION
(
    RECORD_NUM  bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        constraint PK_LOCATION
            primary key,
    PLACEMENT       varchar(255) null,
);
  
INSERT INTO LOCATION (RECORD_NUM, PLACEMENT) VALUES (1, N'North End');
INSERT INTO LOCATION (RECORD_NUM, PLACEMENT) VALUES (2, N'ABC');
INSERT INTO LOCATION (RECORD_NUM, PLACEMENT) VALUES (3, N'South End');
INSERT INTO LOCATION (RECORD_NUM, PLACEMENT) VALUES (4, N'XYZ');
```

- and file /path-to-file/Valid-Values.txt have below content

> North End - South End - West End - East End - Middle

- now below query can give you row 2,4 which is your expected result

```
SELECT *
FROM LOCATION
WHERE
CHARINDEX(
    (
        SELECT BulkColumn
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'path-to-file/Valid-Values.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
    ),
    PLACEMENT
) = 0;
```

Comment: Sahab, thanks for your help.  Thanks for educating me. I appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Good day, Kindly accept the answer if it works for you, it will inspire me to contribute more. Thanks

Comment: @NewToSQL i also have mysql solution for the same, if you like to explore, here is the steps : - first identify folder path where to put  your text file with this query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
- Then run below query 
SELECT *
FROM LOCATION
WHERE LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/Valid-Values.txt') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', PLACEMENT, '%');